# How to prove that causality is transitive?

Tags: special-relativity, causality

Consider three events (events as in the context of SR/GR) $A, B$, and $C$ where $A$ caused $B$ and $B$ causes $C$
$$A\rightarrow B\\
B\rightarrow C$$
It seems reasonable to say
$$A\rightarrow C$$ but can we prove it mathematically?

The motivation of this question is to prove that no two causally disconnected events $D$ and $A$ can ever be connected via an indirect relation. That is if $$D\rightarrow E$$ then $$E\rightarrow A$$ is not possible since that would imply by transitivity of causality that $$D\rightarrow A$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is time-like separation transitive?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746079/)

Comment: See also (other possible duplicates): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100448/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/750454/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/303849/226902